# NoneType() < bool() error when doing pretty format of nltk decision tree classifier

Tags: python, nltk, decision-tree, pretty-print

I am using nltk.classify.DecisionTreeClassifier to classify input sentences into classes. This is the output I get when I train with Verbose = True:

```
best stump for    118 toks uses annual               err=0.6949
best stump for     29 toks uses taken                err=0.1034
best stump for     20 toks uses None                 err=0.1500
best stump for     89 toks uses forward              err=0.6404
best stump for     76 toks uses taken                err=0.6184
best stump for     12 toks uses option               err=0.0000
best stump for     64 toks uses option               err=0.5781
best stump for     27 toks uses use                  err=0.1852
best stump for     24 toks uses None                 err=0.2083
best stump for     37 toks uses leav                 err=0.5946
best stump for      9 toks uses type                 err=0.0000
best stump for     28 toks uses thank                err=0.6071
best stump for     25 toks uses name                 err=0.5600
best stump for     22 toks uses help                 err=0.5000
best stump for      4 toks uses None                 err=0.2500
best stump for     18 toks uses _                    err=0.5000
```

I tried printing the output in pretty format using:

```
classifier.pretty_format()
```

which gives this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-629-dc64618292e3> in <module>()
----> 1 classifier.pretty_format()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/classify/decisiontree.py in pretty_format(self, width, prefix, depth)
     84             return '%s%s %s\n' % (prefix, '.'*n, self._label)
     85         s = ''
---> 86         for i, (fval, result) in enumerate(sorted(self._decisions.items())):
     87             hdr = '%s%s=%s? ' % (prefix, self._fname, fval)
     88             n = width-15-len(hdr)

TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < bool()
```

I am guessing that it made 'None' as a node somewhere.. but I am not sure. I am making sure I do not give any empty values in my data.
Example data:

```
 ({'hey': True, 'hello': True}, 'Greetings')
```

I removed all instances of:

```
({}, 'Greetings')
```

which I initially thought might be the reason for the error.

Can someone help me figure out what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: `self._decisions.items()` cannot be sorted because it contains booleans and None. You can recreate the error with `sorted([True, None])`. Can you post a minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it looks like a Python 3 compatibility issue; I suggest to open a bug in NLTK bug tracker (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues).

Comment: I tried it with Python 2 and it works. So yes looks like a python 3 issue.